# Difference in accuracy with floating point division vs multiplication

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, numbers, floating-point

Is there a difference between this:

```
average = (x1+x2)/2;
deviation1 = x1 -average;
deviation2 = x2 -average;
variance = deviation1*deviation1 + deviation2*deviation2;
```

and this:

```
average2 = (x1+x2);
deviation1 = 2*x1 -average2;
deviation2 = 2*x2 -average2;
variance = (deviation1*deviation1 + deviation2*deviation2) / 4;
```

Note that in the second version I am trying to delay division as late as possible. Does the second version [delay divisions] increase accuracy in general?

Snippet above is only intended as an example, I am not trying to optimize this particular snippet.

BTW, I am asking about division in general, not just by 2 or a power of 2 as they reduce to simple shifts in IEEE 754 representation. I took division by 2, just to illustrate the issue using a very simple example.

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to delay it? What do you expect to gain from that?

Comment: @paxdiablo - that's the exact question - do I gain precision (not perf.) by delaying it.

Comment: actually you should be asking about accuracy rather than precision but the answer is still the same

Comment: Is this language-agnostic? Shouldn't you also worry about positions where type-changes occur? Are they integers, floats, strings? When are they changed into something else?

Comment: @David - yes - I really meant accuracy - thanks for the correction.

Comment: In general it *may* matter (I'd have to think about it more), but with powers of 2, there is no precision lost when you divide unless the numerator is a subnormal (extremely small) number already. So in your case it definitely makes no difference. You could also multiply by 0.5 or 0.25 instead of dividing by 2 or 4; the results will always be exactly the same (since powers of 2 are exact).

Comment: @R -yes - but I am asking about division in general, not just by 2 or a power of 2 as they reduce to simple shifts in IEEE 754 representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to be gained from this. You are only changing the scale but you'd don't get any more significant figures in your calculation.

The [Wikipedia article on variance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) explains at a high level some of the options for calculation variance in a robust fashion.

Comment: The point is I am postponing division to as late as possible. Can you site a reference why they are the same? I know about "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" - but it doesn't talk about this exact thing.

Comment: what's special about division? It's the same as multiplication. You replace divide by 2 with multiply by 2. It's addition and subtraction that you need to worry about.

Comment: But wouldn't there be 6 round off in first and only 2 in second? I should try to reduce round off as much as possible? First: 1'/',2'-',2'*' and 1'+'. Second: 1'/' and 1 conversion. Assuming x1 and x2 are int.

Comment: @logic what are you talking about. 1. Question is about floating point. 2. You don't get round off with int.

Comment: @David : If x1 and x2 are int. Then avg,d1 and d2 are floats in first, and ints in second? I never said round off with int.

Comment: @David - yes, multiplication/division reduces to shifts when it is a power of 2. I was really asking about division in general, not just by powers of 2.

Comment: Division just shifts the scale. Your real problem with variance calculation is cancellation from the subtractions.

Answer (score 2):

You do not gain precision from this since IEEE754 (which is *probably* what you're using under the covers) gives you the same precision (number of bits) at whatever scale you're working. For example 3.14159 x 10<sup>7</sup> will be as precise as 3.14159 x 10<sup>10</sup>.

The only *possible* advantage (of the former) is that you may avoid overflow when setting the deviations. But, as long as the values themselves are less than half of the maximum possible, that won't be a problem.

Comment: I think you mean accuracy rather than precision.

Comment: @David, no, I meant precision as in how precise the value is. The precision is a specific IEEE754 term meaning the number of bits in the significand plus one (for the implied bit). Accuracy is a more amorphous concept since a value with a higher scale and same precision can be less accurate (if you consider accuracy to be how close a number is to it's exact value).

Comment: all floating point values have the same precision then since the significand is a constant size. It seems to me that OP is most likely to be concerned with accuracy and robustness.

Comment: @David: "all floating point values _[of the same type, my edit, just to clarify]_ have the same precision" was exactly my point. The final results will be the same because of that, especially if the divides are both powers of two as shown: zero chance of lost precision due to intermediate forms, unless the implementor was brain-dead :-)

Comment: I clearly don't understand your argument. I don't understand why precision is relevant. What's important is how close you are to the true answer, not how many bits you have in your significand.

Comment: @David, you cannot be accurate _at all_ with IEEE754 if your true value requires more bits than are available in the precision. What my answer is stating is that, provided you don't go beyond the bounds of the scale, or lose precision with intermediate results, it makes no difference whether you divide and multiply or multiply and divide. The precision is the same so you'll end up with the same result. Dividing by powers of two is a simple adjustment to the exponent so will not change the significand, hence my comment that it won't lose precision. Hence you only need worry about the scale.

Comment: @David: further, you _can_ lose information when adding, where the scales are out of whack: eg. `1e300 + 1e-300` is still `1e300` simply because the scale differences are too great. But that's the case with `x1+x2` in both calculations and won't be affected by a subsequent divide by 2 at all.

Comment: Yes I know all that. My answer says the same but I don't use the term precision so loosely. All values have the same precision. A random value will have the same precision as the closest representation to the true value.

Comment: Precision is a term defined in the standard. It's not something I made up :-) And you don't _get_ a random value from those calculations, you get an _exact_ value within the limits of that precision. The OP was questioning whether it would be closer to the real value by deferring the division and that's not the case, _because_ of those precision limits.

Comment: I know what precision is. I know you aren't making it up. It's just not the point. If the question is about finding a method that results in an answer close to the true value then precision is irrelevant. All answers have the same precision.

Comment: Okay, @David, I've tried to explain that it's _precision_ that's the only limiting factor here for this order and type of operations. The fact that all numbers have the same precision _is_ relevant in that context. It may be that my explanation is not adequate or it may be that you're just not getting it - I decline to comment on that :-) If my explanation is inadequate, people will downvote and I'll eventually delete the answer in that case. Either way, I think we've probably discussed it beyond what's productive, the comments are clogging up the system.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with David Heffernan, it won't give you a higher precision.

The reason is how float values are stored. You have some bits representing the significant digits and some bits representing the exponent (for example 3.1714x10-12). The bits for the significant digits will always be the same no matter how large your number is - which means in the end the result will not really be a different one.

Even worse - delaying the division can get you an overflow if you have very large numbers.

If you really need a higher precision there are lots of Libraries allowing large numbers or numbers with higher precision.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer your question would be to run tests (both randomly-distributed and range-based?) and see if the resulting numbers differ at all in the binary representation.

Note that one issue you'll have if you do this is that your functions won't work for value `> MAX_INT/2`, because of the way you code average.

```
avg = (x1+x2)/2        # clobbers numbers > MAX_INT/2
avg = 0.5*x1 + 0.5*x2  # no clobbering
```

This is almost certainly not an issue though unless you are writing a language-level library. And if most of your numbers are small, it may not matter at all? In fact it probably isn't worth considering, since the value of variance will exceed `MAX_INT` since it is inherenty a squared quantity; I'd say you might wish to use standard deviation, but no one does that.

Here I do some experiments in python (which I think supports the IEEE whatever-it-is by virtue of probably delegating math to C libraries...):

```
>>> def compare(numer, denom):
...     assert ((numer/denom)*2).hex()==((2*numer)/denom).hex()

>>> [compare(a,b) for a,b in product(range(1,100),range(1,100))]
```

No problem, I think because division and multiplication by 2 is nicely representable in binary. However try multiplication and division by 3:

```
>>> def compare(numer, denom):
...     assert ((numer/denom)*3).hex()==((3*numer)/denom).hex(), '...'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in compare
AssertionError: 0x1.3333333333334p-1!=0x1.3333333333333p-1
```

Does it probably matter much? Perhaps if you're working with very small numbers (in which case you may wish to use **log arithmetic**). However if you're working with large numbers (uncommon in probability) and you delay division, you will as I mentioned risk overflow, but even worse, **risk bugs due to hard-to-read code**.

Comment: Are you really asserting that simulation with random data is the best way to analyse numerical stability of an algorithm?

Comment: so this is the best way to do what exactly?